# NSTableView with menu, how to change the border color with right click?

Tags: macos, swift, osx-yosemite, nstableview

NSTableView with attached NSMenu.

Upon right clicking on the table view, the menu will appear. With it, the table view will highlight the row with a colored border.

Using the [**HoverTableDemo**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/HoverTableDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) from the Mac Developer Library as a reference point.

The default color corresponds to the user preference from System Preference -> General -> Highlight color.

## Q: How can this border color be changed/removed?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619664/customize-right-click-highlight-on-view-based-nstableview/53315864#53315864

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your TableView

```
- (void)drawContextMenuHighlightForRow:(NSInteger)row;
{

}
```

Comment: It is an undocumented API. Please tell weather it will pass the Mac App store review process?

Comment: I am also wondering whether this has been passed the Mac App store review process.